# Why is my armature only showing in Edit mode

Tags: rigging, armature, bones

I am new to blender and i created a player with armature and some animations, but now they are not visible for some reason in any mode only in edit mode, my keyframes are not showing either, but the animations are working just fine.
I checked the outliner window and the little eye is open and i checked the armature settings for the In Front(x-ray) option and it's active, i don't know what else to do nothing is working... please help!!!

Comment: hit alt+h in pose mode

Comment: it worked thank you so much!